# Feedback on closure reason

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed

I would like some feedback on how to improve my question [Unspecified Implicit Object Creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60626834/unspecified-implicit-object-creation) which was closed as "Needs more focus" by a moderator.

For a bit of background, the question asks about a specific sentence that was added to the latest draft for the upcoming C++20 standard. The standard describes the behavior of programs on a abstract non-deterministic machine. This non-determinism implies that a valid program may have multiple valid outputs ("observable behaviors") and a C++ implementation is allowed to choose any of them. In the standard, rules generating non-deterministic behavior are indicated as "*unspecified behavior*". My question aims at determining whether a newly introduced case of *unspecified behavior* in the standard will actually be able to generate multiple different *observable behaviors* in any valid program.

I think the question cannot be more focused, because it already has objectively only three possible answers: Either there is such a program (in which case it can probably be given as an example) or there is no such program (in which case it can probably be proven) or the question is undecidable.

Or is the problem not really focus, but rather that the question is simply too far removed from an actual practical programming problem to be on-topic for this site? If so, what about other similar questions in the `language-lawyer` tag?

Comment: I have no idea. The closure looks invalid to me. Note that the question went through Triage twice. Probably a victim of a moderator in a hurry, trying to put out a forest fire with a single blanket.

Comment: Question *looks* OK but I'm really out of my depth with C++, especially with `language-lawyer`. So, I cannot vote for reopen in clear conscience.

Comment: Victim of [this *audit*](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/25703219), the mod is cracking down on "requires editing" review votes where nobody other than the post owner could reasonably edit.  He probably didn't see it was an audit.  Why the user passed the audit is hard to guess, there are a lot of things wrong with that review queue.  Anyhoo, the question is open again.